# What's the component name/part number of a motherboard audio jack?

Tags: pcb, audio, hardware, motherboard

I've de-soldered a triple 3.5mm audio connector thing from a dead motherboard and would like to use it for a small project. However, I have no idea what it's called, there's no part number on it, and google reveals nothing (english is not my first language, so maybe I'm not using the right words on the search). Since my college is closed right now I don't have easy access to a caliper to accurately measure pin distances and recreate it on EAGLE, but I'm sure it must be a common enough part to have a datasheet somewhere, right? Here's a picture: [image]

Comment: This type of jack, as a device, is common enough, but we can't tell you an exact part number without knowing the exact dimensions. All I can really say is that it's a group of three 3.5mm audio jacks (with an unclear number of conductors/channels, could be TRS, TRRS, etc) Many manufacturers have made these jacks with their own position/sizing variations, and perhaps if it's on a motherboard it may have been custom-made under contract to the motherboard vendor.

Comment: A part like that, on a high-volume product like a motherboard, might have been made custom, and no datasheet would be available to the general public. Or the datasheet might only be in Chinese.

Comment: It is uncommon enough that you'll probably have to create your own symbol and footprint for it.  If you enjoy electronics, get a caliper - they are indispensable.

Comment: use a row of unbroken pin headers, or the edge of a ribbon cable or arduino socket, as a ruler to count grid holes; they have standard spacing, and I'll bet $0.50 that your socket's pinout lines up with normal pins spacings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I have no idea what it's called*

I searched using "stacked 3 way jack socket" and found this straight away: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.toby.co.uk/signal-to-board-connectors/audio-visual-av/stx4335-kycon-35mm-audio-jack-triple-stacked-in-pc99-colours/)

Comment: That's crazy! I swear I tried everything from "triple headphone jack" to "rainbow motherboard connector" and found nothing. Thank you for your google-fu expertise haha.